# How could I find the sum of digits of $A^{2}$ if $A=102030201$ (no calculator )?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How could I find the sum of digits of $A^{2}$ if 
>   $A=102030201$   (Clearly  calculator is not allowed )?

Okay , it could be done by manually calculating the product of $A$×$A.$
But it will be meaningless question

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $1+0+2+0+3+2+0+1=9$, therefore divisable by 9. So $A$ is divisable by 9 and so must be $A^2$. So the sum of digits has to be of the form $9k$ with $k\geq 1$

Comment: Well, Comman, that narrows it down to infinitely many possibilities.

Comment: It's harder to explain then do, but the digits of the product will have a "diagonal sum" symmetry.  The first digit then the next significant digit is $2*1+1*2 = 4$.  Then next is $3*1 + 2*2 +1*3 = 10$ and because we have zeros as "place holders" we don't need to worry about carrying.  Extending it the sum will be $1 + (2*1 + 1*2) + (3*1 + 2*2+1*3) + (1*2 + 2*3 + 3*2 + 2*1) + (1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1)+ (1*2 + 2*3 + 3*2 + 2*1) + (3*1 + 2*2+1*3) + (2*1 + 1*2)+1  = 36$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{array}{r}\\
&&&&1&&&&&\text{coefficients of  }(x^2+x+1)^0\\
&&&1&1&1&&&&\text{coefficients of  }(x^2+x+1)^1\\
&&1&2&3&2&1&&&\text{coefficients of  }(x^2+x+1)^2\\
&1&3&6&7&6&3&1&&\text{coefficients of  }(x^2+x+1)^3\\
1&4&10&16&19&16&10&4&1&\text{coefficients of  }(x^2+x+1)^4\\
\end{array}
$$

The coefficients of $(x^2+x+1)^k$ can be  calculated recursively in a way similar to the pascal triangle. If the number $a_{i-1,j}$ is the number above $a_{i,j},$ then 
$$ a_{i,j}=a_{i-1,j-1}+a_{i-1,j}+a_{i-1,j+1}$$

And $$(x^2+x+1)^4=(x^4+3x^3+x^2+2x+1)^2=\ldots$$
and so we have to sun the digit sum of the numbers of the last line in the triangle, which is $36.$

So simply multiply $A\cdot A$ by hand to get the result fast:
$$102030201 \cdot 102030201 =\\
\begin{array}\\
102030201 \\
\phantom{1}\phantom{1}204060402 \\
\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}306090603\\
\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}204060402 \\
\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}\phantom{1}102030201 \\
\hline
10210161916100401
\end{array}
$$

---

The problem is more interesting if you pose it the other way round.

> How can you quickly calculate 
>   $$(x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1)^2?$$
>   You can use a numerical calculator but can't use a CAS that can manipulate formulas.

Answer:

Type  in $$102030201$$ in your calculator, square it to get
$$10410161916100401$$
and from this extract the coefficients of the solution
$$x^8+4x^7+10x^6+16x^5+19x^4+16x^3+x10^2+4x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note $102030201 = 10101^{2}$, so if $A=10101$, then you need $A^{4}$. Note that $A=10^{4}+10^{2}+1$.

So we have $$(10^{4}+10^{2}+1)^{4}=10^{16}+\binom{4}{1}(10)^{12}\cdot (10^2+1)+\binom{4}{2}\cdot 10^{8} \cdot (10^2+1)^{2} + \cdots$$

Looks a bit ugly but i hope this helps.

Comment: why do you think that this helps? Is this simpler than calculating the product by hand?

Comment: @miracle173 i think it helps because all the terms have power of 10 which is easy to add and calculate :)

Comment: in the decimal representation of 102030201 all terms are powers of 10, too. in your representation you have to calculate the $(10^2+1)^i$ powers . I can't see  how this will be simpler.

Comment: @miracle173 Hey listen. you just have to calculate $(10^2+1)^{i}$ for $i=0,1,2,3,4$. I don't think it's difficult at all.

Comment: and then you have to multiply them with $10^{12},10^{8},10^{4}$, and then you have to sum the coefficients of equal powers and then you have to check if there are carries you have to consider and then you can start to add the digits. I think this is only a complicate way to do the multiplication by hand.

Comment: Well i agree it's complicated, but i don't agree with your view that "this is only a complicate way to do the multiplication by hand". Multiplying powers of ten and adding them isn't difficult.

Comment: Ugly as hell, in my opinion.

Comment: After writing an answer to this that is similar (but hopefully more explanitory)  I also come to the conclusion the best thing is to just take pencil and paper and multiply this out by hand.  The alternating zeros keep the multiple column borrowing to a minimum and it's not that hard a product to do by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It's harder to explain then do, but the digits of the product will have a "diagonal sum" symmetry.  The first digit then the next significant digit is $2*1+1*2 = 4$.  Then next is $3*1 + 2*2 +1*3 = 10$ and because we have zeros as "place holders" we don't need to worry about carrying.  Extending it the sum will be $1 + (2*1 + 1*2) + (3*1 + 2*2+1*3) + (1*2 + 2*3 + 3*2 + 2*1) + (1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 2*2 + 1*1)+ (1*2 + 2*3 + 3*2 + 2*1) + (3*1 + 2*2+1*3) + (2*1 + 1*2)+1  = 1+4 + (1+0) + (1+6)+ (1+9) + (1+6) +(1+0) + 4 +1 = 36$

===   In detail+++++

Note: $(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i * 10^i)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (\sum_{i+j = k}a_ia_j*10^k)$

e.g.  $abcde = a^2*10^8 + (ba+ab)*10^7 + (ca +b^2 ac)*10^6 + (da+bc + cd+ac)*10^5 + (ae + bd + c^2 +db + ea)*10^4 + (be + cd + dc + eb)*10^3 + (ce + d^2 + ec)10^2 + (de+ed)*10 + e^2$

So $102030201^2 = $

$10^{16} + (2+2)*10^{14} + (3 + 4+ 3)*10^{12} + (2+6+6+2)*10^{10} + (1 +4+9+4+1)*10^8 + (2+6+6+2)*10^6 + (3+4+3)*10^4 + (2 + 2)*10^2 + 1=$

$10^{16} + 4*10^{14} + 10^{13} + 16*10^{10}+ 19*10^8 + 16*10^6 + 10^5 + 4*10^2 + 1=$

$10410161916100401$

And the sum is $36$.

One can also note that $102030201$ has a distinct symmetry that would come with $10101^2 = 102030201$ (by the same reasoning; $10101 = 1*10^8 + (1+1)*10^6 + (1+1+1)*10^4 + (1+1)*10^2 + 1*10^0$)

So $A^2 = 10101^4$ which... well, you can get creative:

$(10^4 + 101)^4 = 10^{16} + 4*10^{12}*101 + 6*10^8*101^2 + 4*10^4*101^3 + 101^4=$

$10^{16} + 4*10^{12}*101 + 6*10^8(10201) + 4*10^4*1030301 + 104060401=$

$10,000,000,000,000,000 +$

$00,404,000,000,000,000 +$

$00,006,120,600,000,000 +$

$00,000,041,212,040,000 +$

$00,000,000,104,060,401 =$

$10,410,161,916,100,401$

.....

Actually, .... just doing the multiplication by hand isn't that hard:

$\_\_ 102030201$

$\times 102030201$

$==========$

$00000000102030201$

$00000020406040200$

$00003060906030000$

$00204060402000000$

$10203020100000000$

$=================$

$10410161916100401$

The zeros and the symettry make it not so hard.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed, and I can't prove this yet, that if the digit sum of $x$ is $z$, then digit sum of $x^2$ is $z^2$.

Comment: I can help, because it cannot be proved. Take the example of $x = 102030201$, then $z = 9$, but $x^2$ has digit sum of $36$ as seen by other answers, which is slightly lower than $z^2 =  81$.

Comment: @mdave16 Well, that's true. I wonder if it works only when $\log_{10}{n}$ is smaller than some constant $k$?